# I have some issue with my output

Tags: java, arrays

The Cullerton Part District holds a mini-Olympics each summer. Create a class named Participant with fields for a name, age, and street address. Include a constructor that assigns parameter values to each field and a toString() method that returns a String containing all the values. Also include an equals() method that determines two Participants are equal if they have the same values in all three fields. Create an application with two arrays of at least 5 Participants each--one holds the Participants in the mini-marathon and the other holds Participants in the diving competition. Prompt the user for Participants who are in both events save the files as BC.java and ABC.java.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;

public class ABC {
     private  static Participant mini[] = new Participant[2];


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        setParticipant();
        displayDetail();

    }


        // BC p=new BC(name,age,add);
    //displayDetails();
        // System.out.println(    p.toString());
    public static void displayDetail() {

        String name=null;
       String add = null;
        int age=0;

        System.out.println("Name\tAdress\tAge");
      BC p=new BC(name,age,add);
        for (int x = 0; x < mini.length; x++) {
//Participant p1=mini[x];
            System.out.println(p.toString());
        }
    }



           public static String getName() {
              Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
              String name;
             System.out.print(" Participant  name: ");
              return name = sc.next();
           }

         // System.out.print(" Participant  name: ");
         // name = sc.next();
          public static int getAge() {
int age;
               System.out.print(" Enter age ");
                 Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);;
                return age= sc.nextInt();
          }
         public static String getAdd() {
             String add;

            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);;
       System.out.print("Enter  Address: ");
       return add=sc.next(); 
         }


    public static void setParticipant(){
        for (int x = 0; x < mini.length; x++) {
         System.out.println("Enter loan details for customer " + (x + 1) + "...");
//Character loanType=getLoanType();
        //String loanType=getLoanType();
        String name=getName();
          String add=getAdd();
          int age=getAge();
         System.out.println();
        }


      }
    }

    //another class
public class BC {


    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String address;


    public BC(String strName, int intAge, String strAddress) {

        name = strName;
        age = intAge;
    address = strAddress;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Participant [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", address=" + address + "]";
    }
public boolean equals(Participant value){
    boolean result;
    if (name.equals(name) && age==value.age && address.equals(address))
            result=true;
    else 
        result=false;
    return result;
        }





}

outPut:
Enter loan details for customer 1...
 Participant  name: hddgg
Enter  Address: 122
 Enter age 12

Enter loan details for customer 2...
 Participant  name: ddjkjde
Enter  Address: hdhhd23
 Enter age 12
//Why I'm not getting right output
Name    Adress  Age
Participant [name=null, age=0, address=null]
Participant [name=null, age=0, address=null]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that output because of this method:

```
public static void displayDetail() {

    String name=null;
    String add = null;
    int age=0;

    System.out.println("Name\tAdress\tAge");
    BC p=new BC(name,age,add);
    for (int x = 0; x < mini.length; x++) {
        //Participant p1=mini[x];
        System.out.println(p.toString());
    }
}
```

You are creating a BC with null for name and add and 0 for age.  You are then printing it twice.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "right method". I think you just have to fix your displayDetail method to print from "mini" instead of "p"